Function Templates as alias
I have a function template with variadic arguments and I wanted to use its instantiation as a template parameter.
template <typename... Args>
constexpr auto foo (Args&&... args) noexcept {
  ...
}

Somewhere:
class X {
public:
  using myFoo = int (foo)<int,int,int>(int,int,int)

  X() {
   // I would like to have something like that
   call<myFoo>();
  }

  template <typename op>
  auto call () {
    return op(1,2,3);
  }
};

The compiler does not accept this code above. Is it possible to declare an alias for a function and to use it as a template parameter?

Does std::function do anything for you?

Not sure if you really want type and not value, but Demo might help.

"an alias for a function" void (*f)(int&&, int&&, int&&) = &foo<int, int, int>;?

Can you show (working) code without template you have in mind. Issue seems not directly related to template IMO.

At best, you can alias the prototype of your function instantiation but it won't let you call your function after (somehow you would have lost its body). On the other hand, you could design your function as a struct providing operator() like this

call has a type parameter but then you want to pass it a non-type parameter

You are confusing types with values in more than one occasion. I assume you want to instantiate call with a callable (a value), not just a type. A function type consists, loosely speaking, of its signature. That's not going to help when you want to call the function.
template <typename... Args>
constexpr auto foo (Args&&... args) noexcept {
    return 42;
}

class X {
public:

  // type alias wouldn't be sufficient here. 
  // Generally you cant call a function by only knowing its type.
  static constexpr auto& myFoo = foo<int,int,int>;


  template <auto op>   // non-type template argument
  auto call () {
    return op(1,2,3);
  }

  X() {
   call<myFoo>();
  }
};

Live Demo
PS: That foo<int,int,int> is instantiation of a function template does not matter that much. Once instantiated, it's a function. You'd face the same problem and the above works the same if you replace foo<int,int,int> with some ordinary function bar.

Great! That's it... I changed typename to auto.

You can make it a no-capture lambda
constexpr auto foo = [/*no-capture*/](auto &&...args) noexcept {};

then apply static_cast<R(*)(Targs...)>. This avoids repetition of Targs:
constexpr static auto myfoo = static_cast<int(*)(int,int,int)>(foo);

Alternatively we can define it as template variable initialized to lambda to get rid of the return type:
template <typename ... targs>
constexpr auto foo = [/*no-capture*/](targs &&... vargs) noexcept {};

constexpr static auto myfoo = foo<int, int, int>;

But this makes the call to original function verbose:
template <typename ... targs>
constexpr decltype(auto) callfoo(targs &&... vargs) noexcept 
{ return foo<targs...>(std::forward<targs>(vargs)...); };

But the simplest would be a pointer to specific instance of the themplate function:
constexpr auto foo(auto &&... vargs) noexcept {};

constexpr static auto* my_foo_ptr = foo<int,int,int>;


Also great solutions! Thanks!

@Code4Fun you're wellcome.
